# How to set a background transparent linear-gradient on an image?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need to set this css :

```
.opacity-down-gradient {
    background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #00000000 30%, #000000c6 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
}
```

To this image :

```
 <CarouselItem key={index} className='relative basis-[33%]'>
   <div className='custom-card-shadow relative h-[400px] rounded-lg'>
       {productSheet.cover?.contentUrl && (
            <img
                className='h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover'
                src={productSheet.cover?.contentUrl}
                alt={productSheet.cover?.title ?? ""}
             />
         )}
```

When I apply the CSS class on my img, nothing appear. Why ?

Here is a [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/liki9tRvmp)

I am using tailwind and CSS.

Comment: Where is `opacity-down-gradient` being added?

Comment: I tried on img and parent div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the gradient you've defined in the `.opacity-down-gradient` class is a background property, and applying it directly to an `<img>` tag won't work, because `<img>` tags don't support background properties like `<div>` tags do.

To get your desired effect, you need to wrap your `<img>` tag with a container `<div>` and apply the gradient to this container. Here's how you can do it:

1. Wrap the Image: Create a container  around your  tag.
2. Apply the Gradient: Assign the .opacity-down-gradient class to this container.
3. Ensure Image Visibility: Make sure the image is visible through the
   gradient. This can be achieved by positioning the image and the
   gradient overlay correctly.

Example of wrapping image and gradient background div with another div:

```
<CarouselItem key={index} className='relative basis-[33%]'>
    <div className='custom-card-shadow relative h-[400px] rounded-lg'>
        {productSheet.cover?.contentUrl && (
            <div className='relative h-full rounded-lg'>
                <img
                    className='h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover absolute top-0 left-0'
                    src={productSheet.cover?.contentUrl}
                    alt={productSheet.cover?.title ?? ""}
                />
                <div className='opacity-down-gradient absolute top-0 left-0 h-full w-full rounded-lg'></div>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
</CarouselItem>
```

You might need to tweak some stuff around but that should help get you in the right direction!

In reply to comments (playground featuring working code):
[playground to working effect (changed gradient color to red for visibility](https://play.tailwindcss.com/B7YDSXnO5G?file=css)

Comment: This make my image very thin. Like 400px by 10px and the background is not applied

Comment: Will edit the code with a potential fix for that. Main thing you want to look at is having the image wrapped by the gradient background div, and make sure the div/image are properly sized relative to eachother, and make sure the relative/absolute postions are accurate to get the overlay effect you want.

Comment: The image is still very thin. I added a playground on the post if it is helpful.

Comment: Sure thing, very helpful. Will go take a look and see what's going on.

Comment: Provided a working playground link where I also changed the secondary gradient color to red. Hopefully that helps and is what you're looking for, assuming you want a gradient overlay on the image.